# Dynamically populate a list in Div

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to dynamically populate an un-ordered list in a Div section. But, I want it on page load and I couldn't find any onload event in the Div tag. I want to make an AJAX request to load list from a .php file.

Which event to capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

body.onLoad or jquery's [document ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready)

Answer (score 1):

Catch `<body>`'s `onLoad` event.